# When i launch an mfc desktop application with rdp, it runs 5 times slower than normal display, keyboard and mouse

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, rdp

Native usage = Put keyboard, mouse and monitor and use.

Remote Usage = Connect over RDP and control it.

We have written an application and it is deployed to Windows Server 2012 R2. It will be used over RDP. The application works as expected when we used the server 'Native Usage'. The weird thing we are faced is it slows down at least 4x - 8x when we use it 'Remote Usage'. It can be thought that network communication is slow etc. but it is not.

It took some time to aware of this issue.

After this we tried to run same application on Windows 10 1903. version, it runs exactly same both native and remote usage. We tried on Windows 10 1809, it again differs native and remote usage.

Can someone have faced with this type of issue ? Any suggestions ?

Comment: Is double buffering enabled in the  "MFC desktop application"?

Comment: I dont know but i suppose it is not